# age matching algorithm based normal distribution in the php

Tags: php, algorithm, math, probability

I think it can be mathematical normal distribution problem, but i want to code in php.
This is the problem.

In my dating site, I want to introduce two women for every man.
There is age base problem. 
Man just like woman who is -8 ~ +4 age. (Of course, it can be different every country. but in china most couples are in this range.)
So the matching score when man is older than woman two years(-2) is highest value, and with -8 ~ +4  age woman , matching coverage percent have to be 98%.

```
$min = -8;
$max = 4;
$coverage_percent = 0.98f;

function matching_score($man_age, $woman_age)
{
  $score = <- some normal distribution function ->;
  return $score;
}
```

I will pick two max scores women for every man.

This method have to 98% probability for all of couples.

Is there any fast normal distribution probability function in php?

Comment: question not clear, although do it using query store all computation on database and when you require just fetch

Comment: `I want to pick two women for every man` Boy o Boy if one can manage even one that's an achievement! two will be a disaster

Comment: sorry my poor english, i changed pick to introduce. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programming languages that I know don't have a built in normal distribution functions, so one has to either get a library or implement oneself.  It's higher level environments like Excel and Matlab that provide that kind of thing.  I don't know PHP, but below is a normal distribution implementation that I use in C#, so presumably you can convert to PHP.  It's got both the CDF (cumulative distribution function) and the PDF (probability distribution function).

```
public class Normal {
    public const double INVRTP = .398942280401433; // INVerse of Root Two Pi  !!
    private const double    y0  = 0.2316419,
                            a0 = 0.31938153,
                            a1 = -0.356563782,
                            a2 = 1.781477937,
                            a3 = -1.821255978,
                            a4 = 1.330274429;
    public static double NormalCDF(double x) {
        double y = 1.0 / (1 + y0 * System.Math.Abs(x));
        y = 1.0 - NormalPDF(x) * (y * (a0 + y * (a1 + y * (a2 + y * (a3 + y * a4)))));
        return (x <= 0.0) ? 1.0 - y : y;
    }
    public static double NormalPDF(double x) {
        return INVRTP * System.Math.Exp(-x * x / 2.0);
    }
}
```